# Should I resign before applying to my next job so I have the reference?

Tags: software-industry, resignation, applications, references

I am about to begin applying for a new job. My only employment in the software industry is the several years I've spent with my current employer. I hear often on here that you should have the next job lined up before resigning. I'm not sure if my situation is an exception to that rule.

- I have a great relationship with my current employer.
- I believe my current company would be a very strong reference.
- I'd like to ask my employer what details of my job duties I am allowed to put on my resume.
- I think they may allow me to work while I search for my next job.
- I work in a high demand industry.
- I have money saved to handle a few months of unemployment if
  need be.

Am I being naive? What are some additional things I should consider when thinking of resigning before having my next job lined up?

Comment: Unless you have a contract that says otherwise, your current employer doesn't get to dictate what *you* put on *your* resume.

Comment: Yes you are being naive. Companies often prefer to hire people who are currently employed and  some throw out the resumes of people  who are unemployed for X amount of time.

Comment: While it's risky to ask a current manager or coworker to be your reference, that's probably a better idea than just resigning, assuming you have a great relationship with them, and it's the very last step in the interviewing process. Related: [How do I get references when still in my first job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15422) [Is having no references necessarily a bad thing?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3127)

Comment: Still being employed is a very powerful form of reference.

Comment: @DanPichelman If one's job duties involve confidential information, then discretion absolutely is warranted. Putting something like "Negotiated purchase of competitor" on one's resume when the purchase has not been publicly announced is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No, no, no.

There is no **guarantee** how long it will take for you to find your next job.  What if you put in your two weeks notice, and it takes 6 months to find your next opportunity?

Do not resign *before you have the next job offer in hand*.  Find another way to meet the reference requirement.  Also, if there are any pre-employment conditions in the offer letter, make sure those are met as well before resigning.

Usually a co-worker / peer will agree to be a reference for you, and you can agree to do the same for them.  Remember one of the golden rules of job seeking:  *Its almost always easier to find a job if you are currently employed.*